# How to create a struct from two arrays?

Tags: swift, data-structures

I have `SearchViewController` and I created "Data" class to load SearchViewController.

```
//File.swift
    class Data {

        var add1: String
        var add2: String

        init(add1: String, add2: String) {
            self.add1 = add2
            self.add1 = add2
        }
    }


//ViewController.swift
//This is the part that I want to load from two arrays of strings.
var entries = [Data]()

entries = [
Data(add1: "Canada", add2: "Ottawa"),
Data(add1: "USA", add2: "Washington"),
Data(add1: "Japan", add2: "Tokyo"),
Data(add1: "Denmark", add2: "Copenhagen")
]
```

My class for search controller's data list goes on. I'll have approx 1000 values. Therefore, I want to load this class from two arrays like shown below.

```
let arr1: [String] = ["Canada", "USA", "Japan", "Denmark"]
let arr2: [String] = ["Ottawa", "Washington", "Tokyo", "Copenhagen"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to iterate the value in loop and appends to the `entries` array

```
for i in 0..<arr1.count {
    // create struct from array data
    let data = Data(add1: arr1[i], add2: arr2[i])

    // insert to your array
    entries.append(data)           
}
```

Comment: This solution (looping) will overload iPhone's CPU in case of big arrays. Better solution with a "zip" function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `zip` here to combine the two arrays into an array of a tuples `(String, String)` and then `map` that sequence into an array of `Data`

```
let arr1 = ["Canada", "USA", "Japan", "Denmark"]
let arr2 = ["Ottawa", "Washington", "Tokyo", "Copenhagen"]
let data = zip(arr1, arr2).map { Data(add1: $0.0, add2: $0.1) }
for d in data { print("\(d.add1) - \(d.add2)") }
```

Prints:

```
Canada - Ottawa
USA - Washington
Japan - Tokyo
Denmark - Copenhagen
```

I also suggest that you change the type `Data` to be a `struct` instead of a `class` if you don't have a good reason for it to be a `class`